# How to preserve the history for STDIN for Perl?

Tags: perl, stdin

I am using STDIN to fetch user input as below. Is there a way to preserve the history from the previous run? That is after terminated the program and rerun, I still can use up arrow key to get back previous input from previous run.

```
while(1){
    $input = getCmd();
}

sub getCmd
{
    print "\nprompt> ";
    my $line = <STDIN>;
    $line =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    return $line;
}
```

Comment: Terminal stores history of input commands which is available to you. If you want to _retrieve_ history of user input then store it in some file, in your script add code which will read data from this file on press **Up** and **Down** keys.

Comment: Maybe something like this Term::ReadKey will help? I'm not sure. Just a suggestion

Comment: From the docs, it looks like Term::ReadLine should provide this, but I wasn't able to actually make history work in the time I wanted to spend on it. Might be worth looking into and posting a (working) answer, though. https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine

Comment: See also [Managing the History File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine::Gnu#Managing-the-History-File) in [Term::ReadLine::Gnu](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine::Gnu)